# Looping through a query and looking at prior record - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this SQL:

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
    SELECT 
        lngTIMEID as Id,
        lngEMPID as EmployeeId,
        dtmdateapp AS [Date], 
        stroccur AS [Value],
        (SELECT SUM(stroccur) 
         FROM [Attendance].[dbo].[timeuse] 
         WHERE dtmdateapp <= d.dtmdateapp 
           AND dtmdateapp >= Dateadd(yy, -1, d.dtmdateapp) 
           AND lngempid = d.lngempid 
           AND absence <> 'Scheduled') AS Total
    FROM   
        [Attendance].[dbo].[timeuse] d
    WHERE 
        lngEMPID =  1162002 AND Absence <> 'Scheduled' 
) 
SELECT 
    cte.*, 
    CASE
       WHEN Total >= 1 AND Total < 2 AND cte.[Date] <= DATEADD(DD, 90, h.HireDate) THEN 'Written'
       WHEN Total > 2 AND cte.[Date] <= DATEADD(DD, 90, h.HireDate) THEN 'Final'
       WHEN Total >= 3 AND Total < 4 THEN 'Verbal'
       WHEN Total >= 4 AND Total < 5 THEN 'Written'
       WHEN Total >= 5 AND Total < 6 THEN 'Final'
       WHEN Total >= 6 THEN 'Termination'
    END AS [Status]
FROM
    cte
JOIN 
    [CSAR].[dbo].[rpt_tblAssociate] c ON c.EmployeeID = cte.EmployeeId
JOIN 
    [CSAR].[dbo].[rpt_tblEmployHx] h ON h.ReportingId = c.ReportingId
WHERE 
    Date > DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE())
```

And it generates a data set like this:

```
+--------+------------+------------+-------+-------+-------------+
|   Id   | EmployeeId |    Date    | Value | Total |   Status    |
+--------+------------+------------+-------+-------+-------------+
| 286320 |    1162002 | 9/13/2016  |  0.00 |  1.75 | NULL        |
| 288479 |    1162002 | 9/29/2016  |  0.25 |  2.25 | NULL        |
| 288523 |    1162002 | 9/28/2016  |  0.25 |  2.00 | NULL        |
| 290832 |    1162002 | 10/17/2016 |  1.00 |  3.25 | Verbal      |
| 290833 |    1162002 | 10/17/2016 |  0.00 |  3.25 | Verbal      |
| 295309 |    1162002 | 11/17/2016 |  0.25 |  3.50 | Verbal      |
| 296655 |    1162002 | 12/1/2016  |  1.00 |  4.50 | Written     |
| 296746 |    1162002 | 12/2/2016  |  1.00 |  5.50 | Final       |
| 298464 |    1162002 | 12/6/2016  |  0.25 |  5.75 | Final       |
| 299658 |    1162002 | 12/14/2016 |  0.25 |  6.00 | Termination |
| 300320 |    1162002 | 12/19/2016 |  0.25 |  6.25 | Termination |
| 302682 |    1162002 | 1/6/2017   |  0.25 |  6.50 | Termination |
| 317070 |    1162002 | 2/15/2017  |  0.25 |  5.75 | Final       |
| 324818 |    1162002 | 3/15/2017  |  0.25 |  6.00 | Termination |
| 330543 |    1162002 | 4/17/2017  |  0.25 |  6.25 | Termination |
| 333859 |    1162002 | 5/8/2017   |  0.00 |  6.25 | Termination |
| 334141 |    1162002 | 5/9/2017   |  1.00 |  7.25 | Termination |
| 336519 |    1162002 | 5/21/2017  |  0.25 |  7.50 | Termination |
+--------+------------+------------+-------+-------+-------------+
```

I want to determine how many times a final status is issued within this data set. In this data that I have shown I would like to it to result 2.

If the data set shows consecutive "Final" then they should only be counted as 1. For example 296746, 298464 have two consecutive final statuses...this should only add 1 to the final status count.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
var finalcount = 0;
var previous = "";

foreach ( var record in recordset)
{
    if(record.Status == "Final" && prevous.Status != "Final")
    {
        finalcount++;
    }

    previous = record;
}
```

Comment: which version of sql server?

Comment: @SqlZim I have 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without re-coding your existing code, you could wrap it in another common table expression and use `lag()`:

```
select CountFinal = count(*)
from (
  select *, prev_status = lag(status) over (order by id)
  from t
  ) sub
where sub.Status = 'Final' 
  and isnull(sub.prev_status,'') <> 'Final'
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/XGT46404

---

Example of wrapping in another cte existing code to add the above:

```
;WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT lngTIMEID as Id,
                lngEMPID as EmployeeId,
                dtmdateapp AS [Date], 
                stroccur AS [Value],
                (SELECT Sum(stroccur) 
                 FROM   [Attendance].[dbo].[timeuse] 
                 WHERE  dtmdateapp <= d.dtmdateapp 
                        AND dtmdateapp >= Dateadd(yy, -1, d.dtmdateapp) 
                        AND lngempid = d.lngempid 
                        AND absence <> 'Scheduled') AS Total
         FROM   [Attendance].[dbo].[timeuse] d
                 WHERE lngEMPID =  1162002 AND Absence <> 'Scheduled' ) 

, t as (
SELECT cte.*, CASE
WHEN Total >= 1 AND Total < 2 AND cte.[Date] <= DATEADD(DD, 90, h.HireDate) THEN 'Written'
WHEN Total > 2 AND cte.[Date] <= DATEADD(DD, 90, h.HireDate) THEN 'Final'
WHEN Total >= 3 AND Total < 4 THEN 'Verbal'
WHEN Total >= 4 AND Total < 5 THEN 'Written'
WHEN Total >= 5 AND Total < 6 THEN 'Final'
WHEN Total >= 6 THEN 'Termination'
 END AS [Status]
FROM cte
JOIN [CSAR].[dbo].[rpt_tblAssociate] c ON c.EmployeeID = cte.EmployeeId
JOIN [CSAR].[dbo].[rpt_tblEmployHx] h ON h.ReportingId = c.ReportingId
WHERE Date > DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE())
)
select CountFinal = count(*)
from (
  select *, prev_status = lag(status) over (order by id)
  from t
  ) sub
where sub.Status = 'Final' 
  and isnull(sub.prev_status,'') <> 'Final'
```

---

With a bit of re-coding, I *believe* you could simplify it down a bit to something like this:

```
;with cte as (
  select 
     lngtimeid as Id
   , lngempid as EmployeeId
   , dtmdateapp as [Date]
   , stroccur as [Value]
   , x.Total
   , prev_total = lag(x.Total) over (order by lngtimeid)
  from [Attendance].[dbo].[timeuse] d
    cross apply (
      select total = sum(stroccur)
    from [Attendance].[dbo].[timeuse] i
    where i.dtmdateapp <= d.dtmdateapp 
      and i.dtmdateapp >= Dateadd(year,-1, d.dtmdateapp) 
      and i.lngempid = d.lngempid 
      and i.absence <> 'Scheduled'
    ) x
  where d.lngempid = 1162002 
    and d.Absence <> 'Scheduled'
)
select CountFinal = count(*)
from cte
where date > dateadd(year,-1, getdate())
  and (Total >= 5 and Total < 6)
  and not (isnull(prev_total,0) >= 5 and isnull(prev_total,0) < 6)
```

Comment: That seems to be what I am looking for and your rextester looks good. How can I use your solution on my query? I don't have a database table that stores all of this data. I just have this sql query.

Comment: Thank you, really appreciate your help.